# PHP file_get_contents and accented URL (4 lines code sample)

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I looked at other questions here and still cant solve this issue. It may look like a duplicate but the answers like adding urlencode of the URL does not work.

I'm trying to fetch images with file_get_contents. here is the code:

```
 $works='http://static.groupalia.it/DealImage/Local/Epilazione-definitiva-con-IFL/Epilazione-definitiva-con-IFL/be71fdb9-4f7c-4e8e-ab4f-4d9742fa1acd.JPG';
 $url='http://static.groupalia.it/DealImage/Local/Hostaria-cacio-e-cocci--menù-x2/Hastaria-Cacio-e-Cocci-Menu--x2/933d79e8-103d-4ffe-b84b-70cf87b14f96.JPG';
 $img= file_get_contents ($url);
 if ( strlen($img) >1000) echo "WORKS!";
```

I'm trying to find a solution that will work for both URLS (the $works and $url).

If I add urlencode to the url gives 'failed to open stream' on both $url and $works.

What is the right solution that works in all these cases?

Comment: you don't need to add urlencode to the url or works url. i copied and pasted the url in a browser and they both pull up images. none of the links have any space or special characters that you need to use that function unless i'm not clear.

Comment: @Nir - It is very late here so I'll give you this to work on which is 80% done but I'll have to go to bed now! `$url_utf8 = mb_convert_encoding($works, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$result = file_get_contents($url_utf8);
echo $result;`

Comment: unixmiah - the $url link has ù

Comment: Thanks inanzzz It seems to have worked only when the source file was encoded in ansi and not when in utf8. I dont know why. See my answer for what worked eventually.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php

$works  ='http://static.groupalia.it/DealImage/Local/Epilazione-definitiva-con-IFL/Epilazione-definitiva-con-IFL/be71fdb9-4f7c-4e8e-ab4f-4d9742fa1acd.JPG';
$url    ='http://static.groupalia.it/DealImage/Local/Hostaria-cacio-e-cocci--menù-x2/Hastaria-Cacio-e-Cocci-Menu--x2/933d79e8-103d-4ffe-b84b-70cf87b14f96.JPG';

$transliterator = Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII');

$img = file_get_contents($transliterator->transliterate($works));

if (strlen($img) >1000) {
    echo "WORKS!";
}
```

But, imho, the best solutions is use e.g. https://github.com/Behat/Transliterator

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this worked:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8'); // required for iconv
$url= iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $url);
```

Hope it helps someone else.